# Python int too large to convert to C long

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando con un archivo excel, algo sencillo mas me indica este error:

> Python int too large to convert to C long

Este es mi código:

```
import pandas as pd 

pat_file = "C:\Proyec\Saldos.xlsx"
Col_types = {"Numero de Cuenta":str,
         "Codigo Contable":str,
         "Número de Producto":str,
         "Codigo Banco":str,
         "Clase Cuenta":str,
         "Clase":str,
         "Saldo Neto con Diferidos (Día anterior)":int}
 hoja = "Hoja1"
 df = pd.read_excel(pat_file,sheet_name=hoja,dtype=Col_types)
 df1 = df[df["Saldo Neto con Diferidos (Día anterior)"] > 0]
 print (len(df1))
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: creo que es por la ruta, utiliza dos barras \ \